# Android Remove Background property in Image view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-event, android-background

I am added a background image highlight in RecyclerView Image:

[image]

but when i click the image previous selected image highlight is also shown.
how to fix this. my code is

```
holder.colorImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            holder.colorImage.setBackgroundResource(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < colorId.size(); i++) {

                holder.colorImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_border);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: What is colorId ?

Comment: @ADM that is array list containing the id's of colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i get from question that one image will be show selected at a time . So its can be easily achieved by saving the selected image position as global, and notify the adapter . Below is an example .

```
 class LAdater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LAdater.ViewHolder> {
    int selectedPosition;

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.item_color, null));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (position == selectedPosition) {
            holder.colorImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_border);
        } else {
            holder.colorImage.setBackgroundResource(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 9;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView colorImage;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.colorImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            colorImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.imageView) {
                selectedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Its just an example modify it as per your need.**